# Convert blob object webp to jpg

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, blob, webp

I am building Chrome Extension that should get src of the image and download it.

The problem is that i get .webp image, but i need .jpg file. Can I somehow convert blob that i get from ajax response and convert to jpg?

```
request.data.forEach((item, key) => {
    $.ajax({
        xhrFields: {
           responseType: 'blob'
        },
        url: item.src,
        type: "GET",
        success: (data) => {
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            chrome.downloads.download({
                url: url.createObjectURL(data) ,
                filename: `${item.type}${key}${item.fileName}`,
            });
        },
        error: (err) => {
            console.log("error ", err);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: The server sees your browser can handle webp based on the request's `accept` header and/or `user-agent` header. You can override those headers either by specifying them in $.ajax or by using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders event in blocking mode with `'extraHeaders'` option, look for examples.

Comment: Does not help, I added in ajax header "image/jpeg" and again I get in response content-type "image/webp"

Comment: Use devtools to inspect the *actual* headers that were sent.